# error installing python wrapper for openkinect

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to install python wrappers for OpenKinect on Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't due this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev 
python2.7-dev : Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Python wrapper requires these dependencies:

1. Cython
2. python-dev (error above)
3. python-numpy

how can I install python-dev?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by running this command

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```